How to add to a ZipFile directly from an open file-descriptor?
I need to take snapshots of a number of Java-processes using jstack -- and store them for future debugging (don't ask). The snapshots are voluminous and they must be taken frequently -- so I compress them into a ZIP-archive, one for each snapshot with a separate entry for each process.
This is implemented using:
def jstack(pid):
    return os.popen("jstack " + str(pid)).read().strip()

pool = Pool(len(Pids)) # Pids is a name to PID dictionary
...
while True:
    snaps = pool.map(jstack, Pids.values())
    TS = snaps[0][0:19].replace(' ', '-')
    Z = zipfile.ZipFile('logs/jstacks-%s.zip' % TS,
        mode = 'w',
        compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,
        allowZip64 = True)
    for name, snap in zip(Pids.keys(), snaps):
        Z.writestr(name + '-' + TS + '.txt', snap,
            compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
...

it all actually works, but it irks me, that the output of each jstack (80-120Kb) is read into memory first, then passed to the writestr()... Even if I never run out of memory, the buffer-copying seems gratuitous.
Can I, perhaps, somehow pass the file-descriptor of each jstack's stdout to zlib directly -- so it reads as much from it, as it needs to at a time?
